# How to reassemble s/w RAID 10 in ubuntu after a disk failure? Currently it has only 3 disks and is showing as RAID 0-Inactive

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm

After a disk failure my RAID 10 system got degraded to RAID 0 - Inactive. It is running on ubuntu 18.04 with components (/dev/sda, /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc, /dev/sdd). How can I replace the failed disk (/dev/sda) and reassemble the RAID 10 system without data loss?

My attempt to assemble the system using mdadm failed with following error:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md126 --uuid abaac928:7741653b:cf17fcec:bf6572d3 --verbose

mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md126
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/md/ubuntu-server:0
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdg2
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdg1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdg
mdadm: /dev/sdf has wrong uuid.
mdadm: /dev/sde has wrong uuid.
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sda (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/loop1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got b4d75336)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop1
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/loop0 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got b4d75336)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop0
mdadm: /dev/sdd is identified as a member of /dev/md126, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sdc is identified as a member of /dev/md126, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdb is identified as a member of /dev/md126, slot 0.
mdadm: added /dev/sdc to /dev/md126 as 1
mdadm: added /dev/sdd to /dev/md126 as 2 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 3 of /dev/md126
mdadm: added /dev/sdb to /dev/md126 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md126 assembled from 2 drives - not enough to start the array.
```

The remaining 3 disks of the systems are /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc, /dev/sdd Here is the status of the /dev/sd[bcd] disks:

```
sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : abaac928:7741653b:cf17fcec:bf6572d3
           Name : ubuntu-server:0
  Creation Time : Wed Jan  8 22:10:46 2020
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 7813772976 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 7813772288 (7451.79 GiB 8001.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813772288 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=688 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : dd5aab0c:b1799a3f:78f4f65f:c89e538b

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Fri Apr 28 23:45:11 2023
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 40 sectors
       Checksum : b2a92143 - correct
         Events : 1912260

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

I have replaced the failed disk /dev/sda but cannot attach it to the system as RAID 10 is not recognised.

Need help on how to assemble the ARRAY and recognise as RAID 10 again to recover the data.